# Second DNS forwarder not working

Tags: domain-name-system

I have DNS server in my network and two configured forwarders. DNS record that only have second DNS forwarder can not be resolved from my client computer. It is like DNS server only ask first DNS forwarder on the list, and never the second one. I have configured 3 seconds for query timeout.

Comment: Is the first forwarder responding at all? If it is then this is the expected behavior.

Comment: Yes, first forwarder is responding. So only if first forwarder is down for 3 seconds second forwarder will be asked for query? I tought that if first forwarder could not reslove the query than second forwarder will be asked?

Comment: No, that isn't how forwarders work. If the first forwarder responds then the second forwarder will not be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behavior: `NXDOMAIN` from one forwarder is a response, and no other forwarders are used unless the query was timed out. However, you may configure *conditional forwarders* i.e. tell that this domain should be resolved using another forwarder (or forwarders). This is possible with both [Windows DNS](https://www.dell.com/support/article/fi/fi/fibsdt1/sln164002/how-to-create-a-conditional-forwarder-on-a-windows-dns-server?lang=en) and BIND:

```
zone "example.com" IN {
    type forward; 
    forwarders { 
        1.1.1.1; 
    }; 
};

zone "example.net" IN { 
    type forward; 
    forwarders { 
        8.8.8.8; 
    }; 
};
```